# The reverse of doing question:Indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is at the 2nd last paragraph of this text. So, skip to that if you like. First, I'll explain what I meant by "reverse of doing question". This is a question given by the book.

Simplify $2^{2x+4}-2^{2x+1}$ in the form of $a^{b-3} \times 7$

So I compare the difference of $2x+4$ and $2x+1$, which is 3.

Then, I tested this:
$$2^4-2^1=14 (2^1 \times 7)$$
$$2^5-2^2=28 (2^2 \times 7)$$
$$2^6-2^3=56 (2^3 \times 7)$$

And.. so on, so the formula is $2^n - 2^{n-3}=2^{n-3} \times 7$

So the answer will be $2^{x-1} \times 7$, where $a=2$ and $b=x$

Anyways, from the formula, I told myself, what if I reverse the formula to form a question?

So this is MY question

> If $n$ is a **POSITIVE INTEGER**, find the value of $a$ in the following equation: $2^{n-3} \times 7=a^n-a^{n-3}$ without using guess and check.

Obviously the answer is $2$ if you have read the whole thing. But what if you want to solve it algebraically and without knowing that you read the whole thing?

Comment: And I can't find a proper tag for this. I don't know the word for describing $a^b$ equations

Comment: $7=2^3-1$ would be the obvious starting point and you are done pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paul is right. Best thing to do here is write 7 as a something subtract 1. Then you have $$2^{n-3}(x - 1) =a^n - a^{n-3}$$ You guess this form from the RHS being a subtraction. Then you deduce

$$2^{n-3}x =a^n$$
By inspection you can see that $x = 2^3$ gives a solution.

This is just something to try in general with weird equations. It may not work in the general case but is usually worth the effort of at least trying to make the RHS and LHS be of the same form.

Comment: EDIT:I find this still assumptive. So I'll explain how u got to $2^{n-3}x=a^n$. So, from the first equation you have given, let's expand the LHS. $2^{n-3}x - 2^{n-3}=a^n-a^{n-3}$ then, $2^{n-3}x= a^n-a^{n-3}+2^{n-3}$ then, you assumed that $a^{n-3}=2^{n-3}$,where $a=2$, such that they can be subtracted to get 0. That is how you gotten $2^{n-3}x=a^n$

Answer (score 0):

So this is from the clues given. I hope I am doing right.

$$2^{n-3} \times 7 = a^n -a^{n-3}$$
$$2^{n-3} \times (2^3-1) = a^n-a^{n-3}$$
$$2^{n-3+3} - 2^{n-3} = a^n-a^{n-3}$$
$$2^n - 2^{n-3} = a^n-a^{n-3}$$

From here, it is obvious that $a=2$ , just like the rule $c^x=d^x$ where $c=d$